# Inner Query Multiple Columns One Database

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have on SQL Table. It is storing the tasks a user is performing. The table has 1 primary key(auto_generated). It has 4 columns, let's say: **Name**, **BadgeID**, **LoginID**, **Task** on which a user can query on *Name, BadgeID or LoginID* column to get the data. Index is created on all the 3 columns. But the data in Column is interrelated.

For Example, Table:

```
PrimKey    Name       BadgeID   LoginID  Task
 1         John Wick  1234      wick     Entered Office
 2                    1234               Printing
 3         John Wick  6789      jwic     Entered Office
 4         Max Payne            payn     Printing
```

While Entering the Office a user has to provide the Name and he has to provide atleast one of BadgeID or LoginID, he can provide both also. For Printing Task, he has to provide either BadgeID or LoginID only. A Printing task can be performed without entering the office also, if you are using suppose a printer outside the office.

For querying the database, a user can query the table with any of Name, BadgeID or LoginID.

If a user is querying with `Name = John Wick` then he should get all the 3 results.
If a user is querying with `BadgeID = 1234` then he should get 1 and 2, if he queries with `BadgeID = 6789`, then he should get only 3.
If a user is querying with `LoginID = wick` then he should get 1 and 2, if he queries with `LoginID = jwic` then he should get only 3.

The SQL Queries I have written is :

The below query is taking 15 seconds:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  (BadgeID IN (select distinct BadgeID 
                    from   table 
                    WHERE ${idType} = ${id})
OR     LoginID IN (select distinct LoginID 
                   from   table 
                   WHERE ${idType} = ${id}))
```

Further Optimization:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  BadgeID IN (select distinct BadgeID 
                   from   table 
                   WHERE  ${idType} = ${id}) 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  LoginID IN (select distinct LoginID 
                   from   table 
                   WHERE ${idType} = ${id});
```

The 2nd query is a little bit faster but looks ugly and non-readable. Is there a way this can be achieved by scanning table twice only, rather than 3 times?

P.S. I am using MySql-5.6.

Comment: Fix the table so all the columns have values.  You might need triggers for this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but that is modifying the actual Prod data. A user looking at it 5 years later down the line will be confused how Printing calls are having Name when the code is only sending BadgeID or LoginID. Additionally, not scalable model also, if any new ID suppose EmployeeID also comes in future then older entries need to be modified as well.

Comment: I'm sure you don't need the distinct part in the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the same structure of your last query, it is highly recommended to:

1. Use `UNION ALL` if you can assure there won't be duplicates, it is much faster.
2. Instead of `*` put the names of columns.

These two basic tips will help you perform faster. Do not forget to index your tables.

Answer (score 0):

A datastore is a repository of data, not a formatting engine.

"If a user is querying with LoginID = wick then he should get 1 and 2" -- That that is what should be stored in the table!

Blanking out `wick` in the output is a formatting issue, to be performed by the application!

Perhaps you need a separate table with `BadgeID` and `LoginID` so that `wick` is always associated with `1234`?  That implies a restructuring of the schema.